# Error message "ubuntu is not installed on this virtual machine Insert the installer disk"

Tags: 14.04, virtualization, desktop-environments

Hi I am trying to install Ubuntu 20 on VMWare, Windows 10.
I thought I had installed the ISO, but when running the VM, I get the error message in the title. The choice is between restarting (with same effects) and change CD/DVD settings, where I see several options, none of which I can click on.  How to proceed?  Thanks

Comment: First there is no Ubuntu 20, it is either 20.04 or 20.10 second why the 14.04 flag?

Comment: What virtual software are you using ?  VirtualBox?, VMWare?

Comment: @Simon Banks,  I'm using   VMWare  and trying  to install Ubuntu 20.04 (there is no such flag yet, so I used the closest:)

Comment: I used VMware Fusion when I create a Ub20.10 image I use the Ubuntu 20.04 server iso.

Comment: I say new virtual machine it asks me for the instal image I give it the iso.  

Then a boot and install the instance.  

Disconnect the iso and it’s all done